# TypeError: Can't convert 'Entry' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to make a little simple app that would encrypt text. I can't figure out what is wrong.

at first it did run but when pressing Encrypt button it would give an error saying that key and filename is not defined.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto import Random
from appJar import gui
import datetime
import csv

def encrypt(key, filename):
    chunksize = 64*1024
    outputFile = "(encrypted)"+filename
    filesize = str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
    IV = Random.new().read(16)

    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

    with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(outputFile, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(filesize.encode('utf-8'))
            outfile.write(IV)

            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += b' ' * (16 - (len(chunk) % 16))

                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))

with gui('Encryption App', '400x200', font={'size':18}) as app:
    app.label('Simple encryption app')
    app.entry('Type text to encrypt: ', label=True, focus=True)
    filename = app.entry('Save as: ',label=True)
    key = app.entry("Password", label=True, secret=True)
    app.buttons(['Encrypt', 'Cancel'], [encrypt(app.entry('Save as: '),app.entry('Password: ')), app.stop])
```

When ran, gives error message:

```
2019-07-07 17:40:44,862 appJar:ERROR [Line 40->1784/__exit__]: ContextManager failed: Can't convert 'Entry' object to str implicitly
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/skyandstars/Desktop/new_score.py", line 40, in <module>
    app.buttons(['Encrypt', 'Cancel'], [encrypt(app.entry('Save as: '),app.entry('Password: ')), app.stop])
  File "/home/skyandstars/Desktop/new_score.py", line 14, in encrypt
    outputFile = "(encrypted)"+filename
TypeError: Can't convert 'Entry' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: check `print(filename)` and `print( type(filename) )`. I think `entry(..)` returns object which is not string and later Python doesn't know how to convert this object to string when you try to add it to string in line `"(encrypted)"+filename`

Comment: Try explicitly converting it to a string with `str(app.entry('Save as: '))`. It also looks like you have the order of the arguments being passed to the `encrypt()` function reversed.

Comment: I see more mistakes in code. I write answer at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this

```
def encrypt(key, filename):
    print(filename, type(filename))
```

and it shows that `filename` is `tkinter.Entry`, not string, so you can't add string and `Entry` in

```
"(encrypted)"+filename
```

To get string from `Entry` you have to use `filename.get()` in all places

```
outputFile = "(encrypted)" + filename.get()

filesize = str(os.path.getsize( filename.get() )).zfill(16)
```

Or you can do this at the beginnig of function `encrypt`

```
filename = filename.get()
```

---

You have the same problem with `key`

---

EDIT: when I run code I see other common mistake from tkinter.

Button need callback - it means function's name without `()` and without arguments - like `app.stop` - but you use `encrypt(..)`. It runs `encrypt(..)` at start and assign `None` to button because `entry(..)` returns `None`.

You may use `lambda` to create function without arguments and assign it without `()`

```
new_function = lambda:encrypt(app.entry('Save as: '), app.entry('Password: '))

[new_function, app.stop]
```

or directly

```
[lambda:encrypt(app.entry('Save as: '), app.entry('Password: ')), app.stop]
```

---

EDIT: another mistake. You create two times entries `entry('Save as: ')` `entry('Password: ')` . One pair will be displayed and you put text in them. Second pair you create in

```
[lambda:encrypt(app.entry('Save as: '), app.entry('Password: ')), app.stop]
```

but they are empty when you press button so you get empty string in function.

You have to use only one pair

```
filename = app.entry('Save as: ', label=True)
key = app.entry("Password", label=True, secret=True)

app.buttons(['Encrypt', 'Cancel'], [lambda:encrypt(key, filename), app.stop])
```

You can even use `get()` at this place instead of using inside `encrypt`

```
filename = app.entry('Save as: ', label=True)
key = app.entry("Password", label=True, secret=True)

app.buttons(['Encrypt', 'Cancel'], [lambda:encrypt(key.get(), filename.get()), app.stop])
```

---

Full code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto import Random
from appJar import gui
import datetime
import csv

def encrypt(key, filename):

    chunksize = 64*1024

    outputFile = "(encrypted)" + filename
    filesize = str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
    IV = Random.new().read(16)

    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

    with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(outputFile, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(filesize.encode('utf-8'))
            outfile.write(IV)

            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += b' ' * (16 - (len(chunk) % 16))

                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))

with gui('Encryption App', '400x200', font={'size':18}) as app:
    app.label('Simple encryption app')
    app.entry('Type text to encrypt: ', label=True, focus=True)

    filename = app.entry('Save as: ', label=True)
    key = app.entry("Password", label=True, secret=True)
    func = lambda:encrypt(key.get(), filename.get())

    app.buttons(['Encrypt', 'Cancel'], [func, app.stop])
```

Comment: Whenpressing encrypt shows error ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long

Answer (score 0):

When you add widgets in appJar, such as: `app.entry('test')` the widget is returned. So, in your code, when you reference `filename` it is pointing at the actual entry box.

If you want to get the text entered into the entry box, you have to ask appJar for it when you need it, with either: `app.getEntry('test')` or with the newer syntax: `app.entry('test')`

So, in your encrypt function, instead of using the `filename` variable, replace it with `app.entry('Save as: ')`